# Unable to hide url bar in TWA while using Microsoft Authentication

Tags: java, android, angular, progressive-web-apps, twa

I have created a TWA and digital assetlinks verification is perfectly working but when I tried to use Microsoft authentication as a login method, the URL bar comes up again, I think it is because of change of host but is there any way out of this, I don't want to show URL bar at all.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please reproduce the relevant  piece of your code and include it in your question to give people a better perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because you're redirecting the user to a site that's not on your domain, it will show the URL bar. This is done as a security feature to prevent phishing on a site that *looks like* Microsoft, but actually isn't.