# Why Redirect brings up the browser chrome in my PWA on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a single-page web application. I would like users to be able to use it full screen by adding it to their homescreen. I use react 16 with react-router.

I use the following code to redirect to Login if a user tries to access a private route without being logged in.

```
isLoggedIn() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={loginPath} />
```

However, when a user adds the page to the homescreen, and everytime they open the app after that (until they log in), that redirection seems to bring up the safari chrome, instead of showing it full screen. The chrome goes away after the user logs in.

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Is your login at a different domain? If so, this may answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66011760/unable-to-hide-url-bar-in-twa-while-using-microsoft-authentication